# ConversionException / CannotResolveClassException in XStream 1.4.4

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I need to read a pile of XML into a Java domain model with XStream 1.4.4. I used JAXB to generate the domain classes from the XSDs, replaced some annotations with seemingly appropriate @XSteeamAlias (though that doesn't seem to make any difference so far). I haven't stripped all of the JAXB stuff out yet, because I've got a lot of classes here, and so far it seems to be going wrong way too early.

An error gets thrown at the second XML tag with text content. Not the first, oddly enough.

Here's my error:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: dateFrom : dateFrom
---- Debugging information ----
message             : dateFrom
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : dateFrom
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /requestedCompany/companyItself/contactDetails/address/dateFrom
line number         : 7
class[1]            : nl.foo.domain.ContactDetails
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : nl.foo.domain.YCompanyType
class[3]            : nl.foo.domain.RequestedCompany
version             : null
-------------------------------
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:79)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:61)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:355)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:306)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:234)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1058)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1042)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:913)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:904)
```

Here's start of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><requestedCompany xmlns="http://www.graydon.nl/XSellence/scorePlus" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<companyItself graydonCompanyIdentificationNumber="891974008">
<bla>bla</bla>
<contactDetails>
<companyName>WONINGTEXTIEL JAMO --VOORBEELDRAPPORT--</companyName>
<address status="huidig" type="20">
<dateFrom>1995-8-12</dateFrom>
<street>
<streetName>HAARLEMMERSTRAAT</streetName>
<houseNumber>179</houseNumber>
</street>
```

ContactDetails.java looks like this:

```
public class ContactDetails {

@XStreamAlias("companyName")
protected String companyName;
@XStreamAlias("tradeName")
protected List<TradeName> tradeName;
@XStreamAlias("address")
protected List<YAddress> address;
@XStreamAlias("telephoneNumber")
protected List<YTelephone> telephoneNumber;
@XStreamAlias("faxNumber")
protected List<YTelephone> faxNumber;
}
```

I'm not sure I need all those aliases. They don't seem to help or hurt.

When I remove the dateFrom tag, is fails on Street. When I remove that, it fails on the next tag, etc. Interesting is that it doesn't fail on the companyName or the unsupported "bla" tag that I added myself.

**edit:** It seems the problem is with the Lists. It's always the first element in an object in a List that fails. Address is in a List, therefore all the fields in Address cause errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for posterity: It was indeed the lists. Before every list, I need to put `@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName ="address")`

This makes it handle lists properly.